# Map which stores derived objects

Tags: c++, inheritance, dictionary, polymorphism

I have parent class:

```
class Data
{
    public:
        Data ( void ) { }
        Virtual int Size ( void ) 
        {
            return 100;
        }
    protected:
        map<string, Data*> m;

};
```

Classes that inherit from class Data:

```
class Struct : public Data
{
    public: 
        Struct ( void ) { }
        Struct & Add ( const string & name, Data x )
        {
            Data * tmp = new Data ( x );
            m[name] = tmp;
            return *this;
        }
        void Print ( void ) 
        {
            for ( const auto & tmp : m )
                cout << tmp . first << "    " << tmp . second -> Size () << endl;
        }
};

class IntData : public Data
{
    public:
        IntData ( void ) { }
        int Size ( void )
        {
            return 4;
        }
};

class DoubleData : public Data
{
    public:
        DoubleData ( void ) { }
        int Size ( void )
        {
            return 8;
        }

};
```

main :

```
int main ( void )
{
    Struct  a;
    a . Add ( "Integer",IntData () );
    a . Print ();
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
Current output : Integer 100
Expected output : Integer 4
```

I want to create a map which would hold various types of objects that are derived from Data class. But when i want to call method Size from stored object in map ( in this case IntData ) which should return 4 It always returns value from parent class Data. How could i fix that please?

Comment: Your `Data` class needs a virtual destructor.  But more than that, polymorphism only works when you have reference or pointer as a parameter.  Your `Add` function is passing an object.  Google "object slicing".  Also, post the real code, as `Virtual` is not a keyword.

Answer (score 4):

There's your problem:

```
        Data * tmp = new Data ( x );
```

The actual pointer you're putting into the map is an instance of the `Data` parent class. You're copy-constructing a new instance of the `Data` parent class from an argument that you're passing, by value, as a parameter.

You need to change this whole function to:

```
    Struct & Add ( const string & name, Data *x)
    {
        m[name] = x;
        return *this;
    }
```

And the caller is now responsible for constructing a new instance of any subclass:

```
    a . Add ( "Integer",new IntData);
```

Then, this will work as you intended.

Of course, this kind of an approach brings up various issues with memory leaks, etc..., so you're better off using `std::shared_ptr`. But that would be a different question...

Comment: Yes thanks for your answer it works fine now but is there a way how to do that without passing `new IntData`  , just by passing `IntData ()` like i had in my code?

Comment: @kvway Please read my comment above.  The answer is "no" -- polymorphism works with references and pointers.  Passing an object by value slices it.

Comment: @kvway If `Data` had a virtual `clone` function and `Add` accepted a `Data` by reference then it might be possible, yes.  But then why do you want to?

Comment: @kvway, use references rather than pointers. `Struct &Struct::Add(std::string const &, Data const &)`.

Comment: @Chris Drew i just want to make it like that. Could you give me some hint or advices how to do it ? I tried something but was getting too many errors.

Answer (score 1):

I've rewritten your code for you.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class Data {
    public:
        virtual ~Data(){}
        virtual int Size() = 0;
};

class Struct : public Data {
            std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Data>> m;
    public: 
        Struct& Add(const std::string& name, std::unique_ptr<Data> x) {
            m[name] = std::move(x);
            return *this;
        }
        void Print() {
            for(const auto& tmp : m )
                std::cout << tmp.first << "    " << tmp.second->Size() << "\n";
        }
        int Size() override {
            int sum = 0;
            for (const auto& tmp : m)
                sum += tmp.second->Size();
            return sum;
        }
};

class IntData : public Data {
    public:
        int Size( ) override { return 4; }
};

class DoubleData : public Data {
    public:
        DoubleData( ) { }
        int Size( ) override { return 8; }
};

int main() {
    Struct  a;
    a.Add("Integer", std::make_unique<IntData>() );
    a.Print();
}
```

[Your welcome.](https://ideone.com/7OzmpZ)

Comment: Please add some explanation, not just the code, to make this an answer with a high value